# php $_POST is always empty

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an example register form with PHP and HTML.

I've got the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    </br></br></br></br>
    <form method="post" action="register.php">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="insert username" required></input></br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="insert password" required></input></br>
        <label>Retype Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="cpwd" name="cpwd" placeholder="confirm password" required></input></br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrami"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP action that gets called:

```
<?php
$username="def";
$password="def";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['uname'])) {
        echo "yes";
        $username = $_POST['uname'];
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['cpwd'])) {
        $cpassword = $_POST['cpwd'];
    }
}
echo $username;
echo $password;
require('connection.php');
?>
```

Nothing in the $_POST is passed. When I try to assign `$username=$_POST['uname']` it will not change the value.
I also tried using `$_REQUEST.`
Any ideas? 
Thanks for any interest you might have in matter!

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: var_dump($_POST);     shows nothing

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your code. How it's used is unknown. Are you using this off a webserver or directly into your browser as `file:///`? If `http://localhost`, then is your server/php properly configured?

Comment: well you're relying on the answers section; if you're not going to reply to my comment, then wait for someone else.

Comment: Is the PHP code you posted from the `register.php` file? Or is there a redirect involved?

Comment: ok so I was wrong. the guy from the comment before was right. but i end up with raw post data.

Comment: i'll try to handle it like this. I would like to mark that answer as correct but he removed it. what should i do  ? (i'm a newbie here)

Comment: If you are not getting data in the POST or REQUEST array then something is quite wrong with your web server setup

Comment: Please is their a way we can know a little about your server setup??

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  what if I'm using xamp i.e. `http://localhost`, what should be done to make sure $_POST is properly set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the user before was right and I would like to give him credit but he deleted the answer. so i'll just repost what he suggested:

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input"); //getting post like this  `
```